# How to check html slider values in Javascript? (either value-1 or value+1)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this slider in HTML and I was wondering how to check if the previous value of the slider is equal with the current value. Please if you know how to do this let me know. Thanks for your time.

```js
var target = document.getElementById("myTarget");
let previous;

function foo(myValue) {
     
    //console.log(myValue);
     
    //Update SPAN
    target.innerHTML = myValue; //EXPECTED = CURRENT VALUE

    console.log(previous);

    if(previous === myValue){
       //Statements
       console.log("same");
    }else{
       //Statemets
       //previous = myValue;
       console.log("different");
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="mySlider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" oninput="foo(this.value);">
<span id="myTarget">0</span>
```

[image]

Comment: What constitutes as a new value? Example: the slider is initially 0, the user changes it to 1. That would be false. Example: the slider is now 1 and in order to ever get true is if the user changes it to 1...explain the logic.

Comment: `value=0`, then change any value let's say `value=4`, then I want to check if the previous value (EITHER 3 OR 5). there are only TWO possible options! This is what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: The slider.value changes on every slider movement. so when a value is selected only 2 possible values should be checked.

Comment: @ChristosLytras How I can store the previous value of the stage. if I never declare it? I know it's stupid I just don't know how to logically think this.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong. but `let previous` is always `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('mySlider');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

var initialValue = 2; // set however you want

slider.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    let outcome = "'"+initialValue+"' and '"+this.value+"' are ";
    if( parseInt(this.value)===initialValue){
        outcome+= "equal!"
    } else{
        outcome+= "not equal"
    }
    output.innerHTML = outcome
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="mySlider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1"/>


<div id="output">
  <em>Not run yet</em>
</div>
```

Comment: You should alway try to use an eventhandler. No only is this better because you split your view (html) and code, but it also somewhat forces you to create a proper code flow, reducing the chance for weird mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Martijn answer I was able to create a loop like this:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider-element_BV");

    slider.addEventListener('input', function(event){

    RAYS_CLASS.Ray_Techniques.RAYS_TECHNIQUES_MANAGER.BV().BV_REMOVE();

    for(var i=this.min; i<=this.max; i++) {
        if(parseInt(this.value) === i){
            RAYS_CLASS.Ray_Techniques.RAYS_TECHNIQUES_MANAGER.BV().BV_Subdivide(i);
        }
    }
});
```

[image]